Creating a column by if else statements
I have a data frame with 4 columns. The columns are:
Home_team,
Away_team,
Home_team_goal,
Away_team_goal
I want to create a winner column by using goals. I wrote the code below, but when I run it, I get only home teams in the winner column.
A = ['A', '1', 'D', '2']
B = ['B', '2', 'E', '2']
C = ['C', '3', 'F', '2']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([A,B,C]), columns = ['Home_team', 'Home_team_goal', 'Away_team', 'Away_team_goal'])

df['Home_team_goal'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Home_team_goal'])
df['Away_team_goal'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Away_team_goal'])

df['Average'] = df['Home_team_goal'] - df['Away_team_goal']

df['Winner'] = ''

for i, e in enumerate(df['Average']):
    if e > 0:
        df['Winner'] = df['Home_team']
    elif e < 0:
        df['Winner'] = df['Away_team']
    else:
        df['Winner'] = 'Tie'


Use np.where().

Here another approach:
def Winner(x):
if x > 0:
    return 1
elif x < 0:
    return 2
else:
    return 0

df['Winner'] = df['Average'].apply(Winner)


This can be done using Numpy .select:
import numpy as np
cond1 = df['Home_team_goal'] > df['Away_team_goal']
cond2 = df['Home_team_goal'] < df['Away_team_goal']

df['Winner'] = np.select([cond1, cond2], [df['Home_team'], df['Away_team']], default = 'Tie')

If you also want to use some sort of overall scoring scheme then use the same conditions:
df['Points'] = np.select([cond1, cond2], [2,1]], default = 0)

which gives for the sample data:
  Home_team  Home_team_goal Away_team  Away_team_goal Winner  Points
0         A               1         D               2      D       1
1         B               2         E               2    Tie       0
2         C               3         F               2      C       2

The conditions could be simply extended to cover other requirements such as treating a 0,0 score differently.

additionally (typed here as too awkward for a comment ....
df['Average'] = df['Home_team_goal'] - df['Away_team_goal']

will throw
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
you need to convert them to ints
df['Home_team_goal'] = df['Home_team_goal'].astype(int)
df['Away_team_goal'] = df['Away_team_goal'].astype(int)

